# Logstash 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' not loaded

Tags: jdbc, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

I have a problem with `jdbc_driver_library`. I'm using `ELK_VERSION = 6.4.2` and I use Docker for ELK.

When I run:

```
/opt/logstash# bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/mysql.conf
```

I'm getting an error:

```
error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?
```

Driver path:

```
root@xxxxxxx:/etc/logstash/conectors# ls
mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar 
root@xxxxxxxxxx:/etc/logstash/conectors#
```

mysql.conf:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/etc/logstash/conectors/mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"
    jdbc_user => "demouser"
    jdbc_password => "demopassword"
    statement => "SELECT id,name,city from ads"
  }
}

output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
        index => 'test'
        document_type => 'tes'
        document_id => '%{id}'
        hosts => ['http://localhost:9200']
    }
}
```

The whole error:

```
root@xxxxx:/opt/logstash# bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/mysql.conf
Sending Logstash logs to /opt/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2018-11-10T09:03:22,081][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2018-11-10T09:03:23,628][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.4.2"}
[2018-11-10T09:03:30,482][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[2018-11-10T09:03:31,479][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2018-11-10T09:03:31,928][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2018-11-10T09:03:32,067][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}
[2018-11-10T09:03:32,076][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
[2018-11-10T09:03:32,154][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["http://localhost:9200"]}
[2018-11-10T09:03:32,210][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
[2018-11-10T09:03:32,267][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
[2018-11-10T09:03:32,760][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x202f727c run>"}
[2018-11-10T09:03:32,980][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2018-11-10T09:03:33,877][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2018-11-10T09:03:34,315][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Pipeline_id:main
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc jdbc_user=>"demouser", jdbc_password=><password>, statement=>"SELECT id,name,city from ads", jdbc_driver_library=>"/etc/logstash/conectors/mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar", jdbc_connection_string=>"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", id=>"233c4411c2434e93444c3f59eb9503f3a75cab4f85b0a947d96fa6773dac56cd", jdbc_driver_class=>"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_cf5ab80c-91e4-4bc4-8d20-8c5a0f9f8077", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, jdbc_paging_enabled=>false, jdbc_page_size=>100000, jdbc_validate_connection=>false, jdbc_validation_timeout=>3600, jdbc_pool_timeout=>5, sql_log_level=>"info", connection_retry_attempts=>1, connection_retry_attempts_wait_time=>0.5, parameters=>{"sql_last_value"=>1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000}, last_run_metadata_path=>"/root/.logstash_jdbc_last_run", use_column_value=>false, tracking_column_type=>"numeric", clean_run=>false, record_last_run=>true, lowercase_column_names=>true>
  Error: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?
  Exception: LogStash::ConfigurationError
  Stack: /opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.13/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:163:in `open_jdbc_connection'
/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.13/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb:221:in `execute_statement'
/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.13/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:277:in `execute_query'
/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.13/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:263:in `run'
/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:409:in `inputworker'
/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:403:in `block in start_input'
```

When I build an image and use `docker run`, I get another error:

```
[2018-11-10T10:32:52,935][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.queue", :path=>"/opt/logstash/data/queue"}
[2018-11-10T10:32:52,966][INFO ][logstash.setting.writabledirectory] Creating directory {:setting=>"path.dead_letter_queue", :path=>"/opt/logstash/data/dead_letter_queue"}
[2018-11-10T10:32:54,509][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

Same problem when I use PostgreSQL.

psql.conf

```
input {
   jdbc {
     type => 'test'
     jdbc_driver_library => '/etc/logstash/postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar'
     jdbc_driver_class => 'org.postgresql.Driver'
     jdbc_connection_string => 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mytestdb'
     jdbc_user => 'postgres'
     jdbc_password => 'xxxxxx'
     jdbc_page_size => '50000'
     statement => 'SELECT id, name, city FROM ads'
   }
 }
```

Then I run:

```
/opt/logstash# bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/psql.conf
```

Error:

```
error: org.postgresql.Driver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?
```

Comment: What happens if you use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` (the new driver classname is MySQL Connector/J 8.0.x) instead?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  the same error again

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and the bellow solution fixed my issue .

for logstash 6.2.x and above, add the required  drivers under:

logstash_install_dir/logstash-core/lib/jars/
and don't provide any driver path in config file.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem:

First check your java version:

```
root@xxxxxx:/# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
```

1. If you are using 1.8 then you should use the **JDBC42 version**.
2. If you are using 1.7 then you should use the **JDBC41 version**.
3. If you are using 1.6 then you should use the **JDBC43 version**.

### Postgres setup:

**postgresql-9.4-1203.jdbc42.jar**

```
 jdbc_driver_library => '/path_to_jar/postgresql-9.4-1203.jdbc42.jar'
 jdbc_driver_class => 'org.postgresql.Driver'
```

### MySQL setup:

**mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar**

```
 jdbc_driver_library => "//path_to_jar/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar"
 jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

Comment: Awesome, your solution deserves an upvote. For me, it worked really well. :)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8 that you're using, the JDBC driver was renamed from `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` (see the [release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html) for details). Just update your `jdbc_driver_class` configuration and you should be OK.

Comment: I remove all images, restart docker, restart PC.
     Update jdbc_driver_class to jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
     Build image again and run container agin.   Error: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, though, I had a different setting: I'm using a virtual machine not a Docker image. The issue was solved by *installing OpenJDK 8* and setting it as the *Default Java Version* on my Ubuntu Server Virtual Machine.

https://linuxize.com/post/install-java-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Hope this helps!

**EDIT :** And before that, I had to change the authentication method of the `root` user from `auth_socket` to `mysql_native_password`

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-18-04